# Add new synchronization connection - NeedsFullImport Error

Tags: active-directory, import, synchronisation, connection

We are trying to setup a new sychronization connection on Sharepoint 2013 however after having filled in our account details and selecting User OU's, when pressing OK the following error is displayed as shown in the screenshot.

**NeedsFullImport**

Any solutions to this would be very useful.

Thanks

[image: NeedsFullImport Error]

Comment: is this connection from different domain or same domain...as this guide they said one connection per domain.http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2011/07/13/3441315.aspx